# Change the DEFAULT console window font in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts, console

How do I change the **default** console font in Windows 10?

I have already made the change to "Cmd.exe", but the problem is I also execute a lot of other console applications by directly executing them (I'm a developer). Each time I launch a new executable I have to change the font to match my preferences.

The default settings have the font size at 11 for some reason, which is too small. I want to make the default size 16 or 18, and have it automatically be applied to any console window that is ever opened on the system.

Answer (score 42):

Right click on the console window title bar, select Defaults, switch to tab Font and choose your desired font and size.

Comment: Is there any way to enable more fonts in cmd or power shell console?

Comment: Especially tricky in French, because it is written "Par défaut", which means "By default". I assumed it was to reset the settings to the defaults, not to edit the default settings.

Answer (score 4):

The Cmd.exe has to be run as administrator for the changes to be saved.
Too add more than the default fonts to the console,  see [the tech republic how to.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/)

Comment: The link is good to check, however it provides only ways to change font to old cmd.exe. In Windows 10 I have new command prompt.

Comment: I've win10 and changed my cmd fonts.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with code page. I am with 936 (GBK) and I guess you have 437 (US English).

Comment: Check the font you're trying to use passes the requirements like monospaced fonts and non italics. I use us keyboard but language settings is English New Zealand

Comment: I am using several, some can be recognised (Yahei Consolas Hybrid) but some not(Monaco and Dejavu Sans Mono), but I think it has no italic and are monospaced. I have posted another question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1202072/change-font-for-non-legacy-command-prompt-in-windows-10-properties-vs-default)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on **Command Prompt** > **Open file location** > in the window you can see the shortcut **right click** > **properties** > save the desired