# Change Default Windows 10 Console Font for Batch Files

Tags: windows-10, fonts, console

The question, [Change the DEFAULT console window font in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/965086/change-the-default-console-window-font-in-windows-10) answers how to set the default font for the Windows 10 Console (command prompt). However, this only works when running the console directly.

What about when running a batch file by double clicking (or via Windows Key-R to run)? The default window sizes I set are there, but the font is back to the original dinky font.

Comment: You may try ConEmu: https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html

Comment: Agree. I'm just guessing, but it seems that a Windows 10 update has changed it so when you open a bat file, it doesn't use the values defined for the command prompt.